# Why does od linenumber increment by 2?

Tags: bash, octal, od

Example:

```
od /bin/bash | head -n4
```

Gives the output

**0000000** 042577 043114 000402 000001 000000 000000 000000 000000
**0000020** 000002 000076 000001 000000 002540 000102 000000 000000
**0000040** 000100 000000 000000 000000 146600 000017 000000 000000
**0000060** 000000 000000 000100 000070 000011 000100 000034 000033

My question is, Why doesn't each line number (shown above in bold) increment by 1?
It goes from 0 to 2 to 4 and so forth.

Shouldn't it be 0, 1, 2 ... 7?

Comment: If you read the manual page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html the numbers default to octal. Each line is 16 bytes

Comment: On each line there are 16 bytes. Each byte is 3 octal digits. (There are 8 groups of 2 bytes each). The first number is also in octal. 20 octal = 16 decimal, 40 octal = 32 decimal, etc.

Comment: Use `od -Ad ...` if you want decimal addresses rather than octal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leftmost column is not a *line number* but rather the byte offset presented in octal form.  Each line of default `od` output has 16 bytes in it.  So, the offset goes 0, 16 (octal 20), 32 (octal 40), etc.